# Infinite loops inside of angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I open up my app in a window, I get stuck in an infinite loop where angular keeps calling the `GameCtrl` and freezes the window. Here's the code:
`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="baseball">
  <head>
    <script src="/js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/vendor/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/baseball.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`baseball.js`

```
var app = angular.module('baseball', []);

function GameCtrl ($scope) {


}

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      controller: GameCtrl,
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
});
```

I feel like this should be trivial; any help would be much appreciated.

### Edit

Even with the templateUrl, it still goes into an infinite loop. Here's the updated config and the template code:
`baseball.js`

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      controller: GameCtrl,
      templateUrl: '/templates/field.html'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
});
```

`templates/field.html`

```
<div>hi</div>
```

Comment: The routeProvider takes template or templateurl for `when` as parameter, where is that?

Answer (score 0):

Add the content you want to display here `<div ng-view></div>`
in your route

```
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
   controller: GameCtrl,
   templateUrl: path/to/your_content.html
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include angular-route.js in the head

and then inject 'ngRoute' into your module.

See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute and http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeProvider

Comment: I tried this and it says no module ngRoute is defined. And I did add the new js file. Also out of curiosity the basic example uses $routeProvider without injecting it into the module. How come? http://angularjs.org/#project-js

Comment: The basic example uses angular 1.0.8. Which version of angular are you using? Your code just says angular.min.js

Comment: 1.0.8, downloaded 2 days ago

Comment: I have created a plunker based upon your description. Works for me.http://plnkr.co/edit/Jmjv4U2xUhDa3twe5alt?p=preview

Comment: Hmm interesting thanks for the plunker and help. I was never able to figure it out, but starting over seemed to work.